# Using the fast adders circuits in FPGA

Tags: fpga, xilinx, arithmetic-division

Im confused on how to use the dedicated carry logic
The first image shows the schematic for a full adder using a MUX
It looks like one of the outputs are equivalent to A XOR B

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Usually you just need to use the behavioral addition operator `+` and the synthesis tools will do the Right Thing. The documentation should give you information about inferring a fast adder, if it is more difficult than that.

Comment: Yes but im interested in physically how its implemented

Comment: Well then you asked the wrong question. You **said** you wanted to know "how to **use**" the dedicated logic. The diagrams you copied into your question show you pretty clearly how it is **implemented**.